# Google Base not working in Magento 1.5.1.0

Tags: magento-1.5, mage-googleshopping, magento-inc

I have integrated google base in my site. I gave google merchant
   details (username and password) in " configuration -> sales > Google
   API" in that google base tab.

And then i go to " catalog -> google base -> manage attributes" then
   click the ' add attribute mapping' button in the right side of the
   page. i got error message like

```
   '`Read timed out after 10 seconds`'
```

I increased timeout seconds upto 360 also . it wont work. what is the
   problem?.  As for my surfing i have 85000+ products in my store. That
   is the reason for the problem to google base throws error?.

Kindly Advice.

Comment: i am also face the same problem.since my store has more than 50 thousand products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to your scaling issues, as I don't use the "Google Base" features and I'm unsure if the Google Base feed generation is well implemented or not.

However, in 2012 Google announced [they were changing their product feed specification](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/2634840?rd=1), and according to [this page these changes started rolling out on July 15th](http://adwords.blogspot.ca/2013/05/updated-google-shopping-feed.html) of this year.  I'd be unsurprised if your Magento 1.5.1.0 site (a version of Magento released April 26, 2011) is incompatible with the new and/or changed Google APIs